# Client sent malformed Host header

Tags: apache, varnish

I keep getting this error in Apache's error log:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] Client sent malformed Host header
```

exactly every 5 minutes. This happens since we installed Varnish on our server, but I can't understand why and how to fix it. I even tried to set Apache's error_log verbosity to debug, but no other useful information is provided. Any idea?

Our Varnish configuration is very basic:

```
backend default {
     .host = "127.0.0.1";
     .port = "9001";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
```

We have several virtualhost that run on port 9001.

Can anyone tell me more about this error and how to resolve or at least investigate about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish performs a [health check](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling) on your backends which might need to be configured more precisely for Apache to accept it. If this doesn't solve your problem, try logging the User-Agent header in Apache to find out who is make the malformed request.

Comment: Is it possible to catch User-Agent inside error log? I already have User-Agent in my LogFormat directive, but I only get the row I pasted in the question

Comment: try changing the interval of the Varnsh health check. When you your error happen at the new interval you know it is Varnish. Otherwise you might need to dump the TCP comms to Apache to see what is going on.

Comment: changed health check every 10 minutes, I keep getting the malformed header message every 5 minutes and 33 seconds.. :/

Comment: Do you have any other health/monitoring tools?

Comment: uhm no. do you have any tool to suggest to investigate on this error (or how to backtrace to the source of the error)?

Comment: it turned out it was a bad setup on the automatic monitor from my server provider, I discovered that with tcpdump, so thank you very much

Comment: Same issue here - our provider has installed collectd to monitor the server performance and the "Client sent malformed Host header" messages started appearing when they installed it.